# segmentation fault on pseudo terminal

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, pty

I get a segmentation fault with this code on fprintf:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int fd;
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    fd = posix_openpt(O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);

    fprintf(fd, "hello\n");

    close(fd);
}
```

But it works fine with:

```
fprintf(stderr, "hello\n");
```

What is causing this?

Comment: Did you check the result of posix_openpt() ?

Comment: fprintf() requires a FILE* not a file descriptor

Comment: You shouldn't ignore warnings you don't understand... Especially if the corresponding line causes a segfault.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a segfault, because `fd` is an `int`, and `fprintf` except of a `FILE*`.

```
fd = posix_openpt(O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
fprintf(fd, "hello\n");    
close(fd);
```

Try [fdopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen) over that `fd`:

```
FILE* file = fdopen(fd, "r+");
if (NULL != file) {
  fprintf(file, "hello\n");    
}
close(fd);
```

Comment: Don't you mean `fdopen(fd, "r+")`?

Comment: Did not take too much attention to `O_RDWR`, so it's a pure mistake. Thank you. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to pass the file descriptor (used for low-level file access) to `fprintf`, but it actually needs a `FILE` structure, defined in `stdio.h`.

You could use  [dprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dprintf) or [fdopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen) (which are POSIX).

Answer (score 3):

To write out to a file descriptor use [`write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html). The [`fprintf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html) command requires a `FILE*` typed pointer.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  int result = EXIT_SUCCESS;
  int fd = posix_openpt(O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
  if (-1 == fd)
  {
    perror("posix_openpt() failed");
    result = EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  else
  {
    char s[] = "hello\n";
    write(fd, s, strlen(s));

    close(fd);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I need to use fprintf().